# Nodejs+Express+Cluster How to use same port?

Tags: node.js, express

So I am experimenting with clustering and running into "Error: bind EADDRINUSE null".

Condenses(and tested) code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

// Create a worker for each CPU
for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
}
} else {
    var https = require('http');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var serv = https.createServer(app);
    serv.listen(80);
    console.log("Server started.");
}
```

Obviously it is because my workers are binding to the same port. connections to client are continuous and a bit intensive. I would like to load balance inbound connections to workers. Is there a way my master can pass connections to workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first answer is correct tho. But I want you to clear a bit about clustering. The concept of clustering or forking your app into multiple multiple processes doesn't mean that running multiple app on different port. Actually, the concept is Distribution.

Shortly, Assuming your app is running at port 3000 with only one process. To make it capable to take more load or distribute the load over multiple processes we do clustering. So I think you are clear and shouldn't arise the different port question after that.

So Yeah the first answer is correct, to do by own, either way, you can do it PM2.

Comment: Whats the with pm2? I hope at somepoint to do multiple machines and using a database to share any data between each worker.

Comment: PM2 is a process manager you can check [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for more. 
Yeah, sharing data between worker that's true, but not about different port.

Comment: Well with multiple machines the port doesn't change only the IP. I figure i would need a machine to push connections :/

Answer (score 4):

I've trimmed down the Express boiler plate a bit, but this is the general idea:

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var cluster = require('cluster');

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

// Code to run if we're in the master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {

  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
      cluster.fork();
  }

} else {
  var server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
}

cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
  console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
  cluster.fork();
});

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

The key difference here, is `var app = require('../app');` at the top.

`app` exports an express instance. You're creating one per worker.

Try re-arranging your code to:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var https = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    var serv = https.createServer(app);
    serv.listen(80);
    console.log("Server started.");
}
```

The important part is this

```
var serv = https.createServer(app);
serv.listen(80);
```

Making each form of the server listen on port 80 - rather than creating separate instances of `app` which all try to bind and listen on that port, resulting in the EADDRINUSE error.

Comment: Whoa. It works just not sure how. Doesnt all the workers attempt to take the same connection when a new connection comes in?

Comment: So on the console i see connected sockets but then the connection drops. "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" it does this continuously after adding the clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Also, could use PM2 clusters, if you are using pm2 process manager. Above that an ngnix proxy server could act as a load balancer as well.

Comment: Whats the with pm2? I hope at somepoint to do multiple machines and using a database to share any data between each worker.